# Tomcat 6 Issue in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to run my web application on tomcat v6, I was testing it on v7 and it worked perfectly but for this assignment it has to run on v6. When I right click on the web application and `run as -> run on server` and select `tomcat v6.0 server at localhost` I can't seem to click the `finish` button. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that step?

Comment: @adarshr uploaded a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly says "The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web Module specification".

Just change your web.xml to have the 2.5 version.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Be sure to change the Project Facet too, by right clicking on the project and doing as shown here:

[image]

Comment: You need to change the Project Facet then.